# Bootstrap table-deleting a row from the DOM destroys the ability to add anymore rows to the table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, frontend

Apologize upfront, I am very new to Bootstrap and JS. Trying to create a Table with Bootstrap that a user can add data to but also remove their entry. Everything seems alright with the adding but when you delete a row from the table using the created button it removes the ability to add anymore rows when entering user data.

This is the table I am using. I have some static data to make it seem like the page is retaining data from a DB.

```
<div class="col-auto">
        <table id="coffee-table" class="table table-active gFont">
          <thead>
            <tr class="text-danger">
              <th class="col-auto">First</th>
              <th class="col-auto">Last</th>
              <th class="col-auto">Favorite Coffee</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="item-0">
              <td>Larry</td>
              <td>Bird</td>
              <td>Iced Coffee</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="item-1">
              <td>Jesse</td>
              <td>Watch</td>
              <td>Latte</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="item-2">
              <td>Tiger</td>
              <td>Woods</td>
              <td>Cappuccino</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

JS code for adding to the table and making/adding the delete button to the user created row.

```
let id = 3;

document.getElementById("add-coffee-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let table = document.getElementById("coffee-table");
  let row = table.insertRow(id + 1); //Trying to insert at bottom of Table
  row.setAttribute("id", `item-${id}`);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("last-name").value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(
    "favorite-coffee"
  ).value;
  //   row.insertCell(3).appendChild(deleteButton(id++));
  document.getElementById("first-name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("last-name").value = "";
  row.insertCell(3).appendChild(makeDeleteBtn(id++));
  document.getElementById("favorite-coffee").value = "";
});

function makeDeleteBtn(id) {
  let btn = document.createElement("button"); // <button> </button>
  btn.className = "btn btn-primary"; //<button class="btn btn-primary"></button>
  btn.id = id; //<button class="btn btn-primary" id="3"></button>
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete"; //<button class="btn btn-primary" id="3"> Delete</button>
  btn.onclick = () => {
    document
      .getElementById(`item-${id}`)
      .parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(`item-${id}`));
    id--;
  };

  return btn;
}
```

Comment: Please check and share the error in the browser's console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking id as static and once you are adding a row you are incrementing the id. But when you are deleting a row, the new id for adding an element changes. You can use **table.rows.length** for getting id dynamically. It will give the number of **tr** in table. So, you just need to exclude header tr. Try below code :

```
let id = 3;

document.getElementById("add-coffee-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let table = document.getElementById("coffee-table");
  console.log(table.rows.length);
  let row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); //Trying to insert at bottom of Table
  row.setAttribute("id", `item-${table.rows.length - 2}`);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = document.getElementById("first-name").value;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("last-name").value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = document.getElementById(
    "favorite-coffee"
  ).value;
  //   row.insertCell(3).appendChild(deleteButton(id++));
  document.getElementById("first-name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("last-name").value = "";
  row.insertCell(3).appendChild(makeDeleteBtn(table.rows.length - 2));
  document.getElementById("favorite-coffee").value = "";
});

function makeDeleteBtn(id) {
console.log(id);
  let btn = document.createElement("button"); // <button> </button>
  btn.className = "btn btn-primary"; //<button class="btn btn-primary"></button>
  btn.id = id; //<button class="btn btn-primary" id="3"></button>
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete"; //<button class="btn btn-primary" id="3"> Delete</button>
  btn.onclick = () => {
    document
      .getElementById(`item-${id}`)
      .parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(`item-${id}`));
    id--;
  };

  return btn;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton! That fixed it for me. AH ok I think I get it. Thanks again!

Comment: Do I still need to declare the let id= 3 at the very top if I use table.rows.length?

Comment: You don't need to add id=3 as now you will be using dynamic row length.

Comment: This is super slick! Thanks so much! I had no idea you could use .length here! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: If you think it worked, you can accept this answer.

Comment: sorry I am so new to all this. I don't see the option to accept your response as the answer.  That is what you're saying to do, correct?

Comment: I have not asked any questions. But I think this would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yeah sorry I totally missed the GIANT check mark to accept your response as the answer. I figured it out though. Thanks again for your help!